# Magento 2: How to override default logger?

Tags: module, magento2, logging

I want all my log files to be send to a certain server by using this snippet in a custom module

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;
$log = new Logger('Test');
$log->pushHandler(new SyslogUdpHandler("MyLogServer", 5000));
$log->addError("ERRORRRRRR::");
```

Is there a common place where I can register this new logger, so that every new log is processed by this handler and not written into files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set preference for `LoggerInterface` in `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml`. This will make your logger default systemwide:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\CustomLogger" />
</config>
```

Note that `CustomLogger` must implement `LoggerInterface` in this case.

Comment: but is this stil valid when I rely on Monolog?

Comment: It is up to you what will be the implementation. It should be ok to extend `Monolog\Logger` like Magento does `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog`.

Comment: I just made a preference and extended \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog and used my own handlers in the constructor, and its working fine:)

Comment: @xhalli : I am also trying to extend `\Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog` by using preference. But I am getting error `InvalidArgumentException: Cache frontend 'default' is not recognized.`  Please help me out.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh it would be best to open a new question with more detailed information where you display what you've done so far, to help you as best as possible

Comment: Thank you, I have raised separate ticket 
[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183785/magento-2-invalidargumentexception-cache-frontend-default-is-not-recognized)